# Hyper-V and Linux VM Network Card Issues

Tags: linux, hyper-v-server-2012, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I am facing the issue on the network card Please help me in this regards.

I have Windows Server 2012 on which Hyper-V is installed. We are maintaining the VM (Virtual Machine) on Hyper-V. I have got One VM with "Oracle Unbreakable Linux 6.5" on which my Oracle Production server is running. We have 3 Hyper V Servers with clustering. When I migrate my Oracle VM from one Host  to another Host then "Oracle Unbreakable Linux" forgot the old Network card and pick up a new one. Because of this all the network services are down then I have to reconfigure the old network card and then start the production.

Please could any one tell me why Linux is behaving this, and what is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked Microsoft's [best practices for running Linux on Hyper-V](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn720239.aspx)? In particular, you might want to look at using a static MAC address to prevent network loss after migraitions.

> Linux virtual machines that will be deployed using failover clustering
>   should be configured with a static media access control (MAC) address
>   for each virtual network adapter. In some versions of Linux, the
>   networking configuration may be lost after failover because a new MAC
>   address is assigned to the virtual network adapter. To avoid losing
>   the network configuration, ensure that each virtual network adapter
>   has a static MAC address. You can configure the MAC address by editing
>   the settings of the virtual machine in Hyper-V Manager or Failover
>   Cluster Manager.